# Visual Studio redirect to output to file and stdout at the same time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdout, output-redirect

I wish to run a debug session in Visual Studio and redirect the output to a file while also seeing it in the console in real-time.
I am able to redirect using `> out.txt` in the arguments field of the project's properties, but of course nothing shows in the console.
I am familiar with the powershell `tee` command to I downloaded [wintee](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/), which works fine in cmd. I tried using `| wintee out.txt` in the arguments field, but it just passes those as arguments to the process and `wintee` is never run.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can stop looking for a solution, that's not going to work.  A text file viewer that automatically updates the view when the file changes is going to be handy.  I use the Far utility and never had to look for anything else.

Comment: Disappointing...